# How do I setup a static spa app under a spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, svelte, vite

I am currently writing a hybrid spa app using spring boot as my backend.
I am using the default settings for static resource paths.
[Path setup representing a default project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaH1N.png)

My Url is http://localhost:8080/ for the main app and /s for the spa app.
I tried going to the url http://localhost:8080/s/ without index.html and then it says 404 not found.
Then i tried going to the url: http://localhost:8080/s/index.html and it does not work the app does not load i get a white screen.

What am i missing in my spring boot app or in the way I am using Vite + Svelte?

My spring boot app is using spring security for the app.

**UPDATE**: Added Code to hopefully help with answering

```
@Configuration
public class ViewConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setOrder(999)
                .addResourceHandler("/s/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/s/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/s").setViewName("redirect:/s/");
        registry.addViewController("/s/").setViewName("forward:/s/index.html");
    }
}
```

Spring Security Setup:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/client.css", "/client.js").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic();


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Autowired
    protected void configureAuth(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    }

}
```

Comment: There is far too little information here. Show your configuration (as code not as links to images please), what have you configured etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you so much added my configuration code for spring boot

Comment: Remove the `WebMvcConfigurer` I believe that makes things worse, also make sure you don't have any `@EnableWebMvc` on another class as that will disable Spring Boot autoconfiguration.